# Generic method with implicit cast to Guid

Tags: c#, generics, guid

I have actually a method for reading a value from a special data row of an Feature object:

```
    private static T GetRowValueByMethod<T>(Feature feature, string fieldName)
    {
        return (T) feature.GetDataRow(fieldName)[fieldName];
    }
```

This works fine for most values, but with `Guid` I have a problem. If the field contains a `System.Guid` object, then everything is fine. But if it contains a string value then i got an error, because Guid is not castable implicit from string.

To get a `Guid` object from a string it is necessary to create a new Guid object by Guid constructor.
But returning a `Guid` object is not allowed here.
Creating a new `T` object is not possible.
Creating a `Guid` object and casting to `T` is also not possible. So what to do?

I tried something like that, but this does not work (caution: fake code)

```
    private static T GetRowValueByMethod<T>(Feature feature, string fieldName)
    {
        var obj = feature.GetDataRow(fieldName)[fieldName];
        if (obj.ToString().IsAGuid())
        {
            return (T) new Guid(obj.ToString());
        }

        return (T) obj;
    }
```

Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to cast a `Guid` to `T`. That cannot happend since There is not conversion from `Guid` to `T`. It will work if you first put the `Guid` value in an `object`.

Try this:

```
private static T GetRowValueByMethod<T>(Feature feature, string fieldName)
{
    object obj = feature.GetDataRow(fieldName)[fieldName];
    if (obj.ToString().IsAGuid())
        obj = new Guid(obj.ToString());
    return (T)obj;
}
```